# How to use min() Function for floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, min

I am trying to find out the minimum value within a user define function.The values that are within the loop are float.But somehow I was unable to use min function for my conditional statement.My code is given below:

```
def life_age(x):
    for i in range(1,16):
        if 0<min(x[f'age_{i}'])<18:
            return 1
```

Comment: Typo? `if 0<min(x[f'age_{i}'])<18:`

Comment: No..I didn't get any typo error

Comment: @paul You should because the if-statement doesn't have a body. This is not legal Python. Create a [mre].

Comment: @paul, could you give a sample of `x`?

Comment: In the span of 5 minutes, you've given us 3 different code snippets. How do we know this is the correct one? Also, read the link [mre]. We have no idea what `x` is. [Edit] the question to include a full example and **test** that it give you the problem you're claiming it does.

Comment: This is the final draft

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `x` here is expected to look something like this:

```
x = {'age_1': 12.0, 'age_2':43.4, ..., 'age_16':90}
```

And you want to find out if the minimum age value is between 0 and 18.

The problem you are having is that `min()` is expecting an iterable of values like a list, but you are only passing it a single value.

So, you want to pass `min()` the entire list that you want it to find the minimum of:

```
def life_age(x):
   ages = [x[f'age_{i}'] for i in range(1,16)]
   if 0 < min(ages) < 18:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```